# Not able to access cassandra from ISTIO deployed in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I have used Istio deployment tool to install Istio in Google Kubernetes Engine, once after I have deployed my application I am not able to access Cassandra cluster but from outside I am able to access cluster ,I have verified firewall as well. if I deploy my application with out istio then application can able to access cassandra. I have used default setting while deploying ISTIO. my cassandra running port 9042. help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled Istio injection then it worked fine. command used to disable

kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=false

Comment: By disabling the istio-injection you are not deploying the sidecar containers. It's the same of not using the Istio features...

Comment: If I enable istio-injection I am getting below error.

"upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers".

not sure how to resolve but surprisingly sample application is accessible but not my application...

Comment: What Istio version are you using? There is a [known error](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/9805) introduced somewhere between the Istio 1.0.1 and 1.0.3 which causes Pilot not removing stale endpoints. It's fixed on Istio [1.0.4](https://istio.io/about/notes/1.0.4/). The error can be temporarily fixed by deleting the Pilot pod (the newly created pod will recreate the endpoints list).  Give it a try, and update your Istio version if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

See https://istio.io/blog/2018/egress-tcp/ on how to configure access from Istio to external TCP services.

Comment: thanks for the input. Now I able to connect cassandra but not able to connect to internal pod (zookeeper) running on port 2181, can you please suggest the solution.

Comment: @ManikantaReddyP can you provide more information about this problem? What are the origin and the destination of your request?

Comment: I am running zookeeper in Kubernetes pod , created service for zookeeper by exposing port 2181 and my application running in another pod trying to access zookeeper with port 2181 but it is not able to access.

Comment: Note https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/spec-requirements/ , you have to give your zookeeper port a name with `tcp-` prefix, e.g. `tcp-zookeeper`.